# Logica de almacenamiento de datos - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una consulta, tengo un campo que almacena la respuesta de la pregunta, que se encuentra con el radio_button "Si", sin embargo, no estoy seguro en donde deberian de almacenarse las subopciones, lo mas rapido que se me viene a la mente es crear un campo adicional en la misma tabla que almacena las respuestas, algo como SubAnswer, o crear una tabla adicional en donde se vayan anidando cada suboopcion, y referenciar dicha tabla a la tabla principal, pero agradeceria una sugerencia de la mejor forma para realizar esto

Comment: por favor date el tiempo de revisar [ask], esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones, motivo para que termine cerrada

Comment: acota tu publicación a una duda técnica específica, medible y comprobable por la comunidad

Comment: Gracias por la correccion, pero no hacia falta el voto bajo, con la sugerencia hubiese bastado para corregir el problema amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambas opciones son válidas, agregar un campo o crear una tabla, sin embargo decidir entre una u otra va más en la naturaleza de tu problema y para qué vayas a requerir dicha información.

Si va a ser solo para mostrar esa información más adelante, creo que con un campo para guardar la información sería suficiente. Podrías crear un campo de tipo string, donde serialices un array donde guardes esa información, o un campo de tipo jsonb (en postgresql, desconozco si existe en otros engines) que es mucho más versatil a la hora de realizar consultas. Ahora, si piensas realizar consultas más intensivas, donde consultes miles o millones de negocios y necesites filtrar entre los que usan una u otra red social, quizás sería una buena opción crear una tabla.

Personalmente, elegiría un campo en vez de una tabla que es más fácil de implementar y más mantenible. Si ves la necesidad a futuro de escalar, ya que ha crecido bastante la cantidad de registros en tu tabla, podría considerar crear una nueva tabla y migrar esa información.

Comment: Tremendo Alter! Muy bien descrito, te agradezco!

Answer (score 1):

solo podrías crean un enum y al almacenarlo en un

> enum

ejemplo: `enum red-social: {Faecebook: 0, twitter: 1, Instagram: 2}`

la documentación por si te interesa: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Te agradezco por responder Dannis! Ese enum deberia de almacenarlo siempre dentro de la tabla principal, creando unicamente un campo anexo, llamado algo como subanwer, recuerda es una subrespuesta a la principal

Comment: es correcto solo necesitarías agregar el campo "subanwer"

Comment: Excelente! Dannis! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Pero enum serviría solo para guardar una única opción. Por lo que veo en la pregunta podría elegirse más de una red social

Comment: Exacto Alter! Tendria q utilizar una especie de Array, para almacenar mas de una opcion